# Bug in TextArea control of Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

```
<s:TextArea id="txtAddress" x="118" y="31" width="150" height="88" maxChars="100"
                                tabIndex="2"/>

txtAddress.text="AAAAAAAAAAAA CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC P OABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZWSDER-682021";
```

This actionscript code crashes flash plugin. Some times it will not crash but the text inside the text area will be overwrite twice. The same is happening with every browser I have tested. I think this is flash's bug.
**(Please note that if width of the textarea or if the value changes, it will work fine)**
Can any one comment on this?

**Below is the markup code:**

```
<s:BorderContainer x="2" y="32" height="125" width="565"  borderColor="#488AC7" 
                           backgroundColor="#EEF0EE" cornerRadius="2">
            <s:TextInput id="txtPhoneNo" x="407" y="3" width="150" maxChars="15" tabIndex="3"/>
            <s:Label x="12" y="13" text="Name" fontWeight="normal" />
            <s:TextInput x="118" y="3" width="150" id="txtName" maxChars="100" tabIndex="1" />
            <s:Label x="12" y="40" text="Address" fontWeight="normal"/>
            <s:TextArea id="txtAddress" x="118" y="31" width="150" height="88" maxChars="100"
                        tabIndex="2"/>
            <s:Label  x="302" y="13" text="Phone No." fontWeight="normal"/>
            <s:Label x="302" y="40" text="Mobile" fontWeight="normal" />
            <s:TextInput id="txtMobile" x="407" y="31" width="150" maxChars="15" tabIndex="4"/>
            <s:Label x="302" y="70" text="Email" fontWeight="normal" />
            <s:TextInput id="txtEmail" x="407" y="60" width="150" maxChars="100" tabIndex="5"/>
            <s:Label x="302" y="101" text="ECS Account NO"/>
            <s:TextInput id="txtECSAcNo" x="407" y="91" width="150" tabIndex="6"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is isolated to your system or implementation.

What you have provided is functional:

[image: text area]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                txtAddress.text = "AAAAAAAAAAAA CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC P OABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZWSDER-682021";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea id="txtAddress"
                x="118"
                y="31"
                width="150"
                height="88"
                maxChars="100"
                tabIndex="2" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your review.. I am updating the textatrea inside a button click handler. Please clear your plugin cache and update the text inside a button click handler.

Comment: No difference - perfectly fine.  Again, this is likely caused elsewhere in your implementation.  Perhaps an item renderer or parent component is causing this.  Install Flash Debug player and provide specifics of the crash.  Font appearing as "doubled" is typically a lifecycle issue per your Flex implementation.

Answer (score 0):

it seems somewhere else, you set the fontsize of the textarea to an invalid value. I had the same problem before, maybe somewhere you just set it to some value like "10px".